# aws amplify gen 2 auth userAttributes, 'name' does not exist in type 'StandardAttributes'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

With 'name' in amplify/auth/resource.ts as sign-up required attribute I've got error "'name' does not exist in type 'StandardAttributes'":

```
import {defineAuth} from '@aws-amplify/backend';

export const auth = defineAuth({
    loginWith: {
        email: true
    },
    userAttributes: {
        // require the attribute be provided during sign-up
        name: {
            required: true,
            mutable: true
        },
    }
});
```

and if if I try npx amplify sandbox, error "TypeScript validation check failed, check your backend definition"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, even if 'name' is part of OpenID specs and doesn't work for unknown reason, for now I'll use given name and family name, like below, instead:

```
import {defineAuth} from '@aws-amplify/backend';

export const auth = defineAuth({
    loginWith: {
        email: true
    },
    userAttributes: {
        // require the attribute be provided during sign-up
        givenName: {    // Given name or first name
            required: true,
            mutable: true
        },
        familyName: {
            required: true,
            mutable: true
        },
    }
});
```